# Multiple check if User have reached an expected DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-analytics

I am trying to use a modified version of Justin Cutroni's Javascript to track and analyse user behaviour. For example, I want to know how much time does an user needed to reach the end of the content div and (taking the number of words in the article into consideration), determine if the user has just scanned the site. I use this piece of code:

```
// If user has hit the bottom of the content send an event
if (bottom >= $('#lorem').scrollTop() + $('#lorem').innerHeight() && !endContent) {
    currentTime = new Date();
    contentScrollEnd = currentTime.getTime();
    timeToContentEnd = Math.round((contentScrollEnd - scrollStart) / 1000);

    var palabras = document.getElementById('lorem').innerHTML.split(' ').length;

    var tiempo_estimado_lector =  Math.round(palabras / 400)*60;
    var tiempo_estimado_lector_intensivo =  Math.round(palabras / 250)*60;

    if (timeToContentEnd < tiempo_estimado_lector) {
    var tipo_lector = "Escaneador";
    } else if (timeToContentEnd < tiempo_estimado_lector_intensivo) {
        var tipo_lector = "Lector";
        } else {
        var tipo_lector = "Lector intensivo";
        }
    if (!debugMode) {
        ga('set', 'dimension5', tipo_lector); 
        ga('send', 'event', 'Reading', 'ContentBottom', pageTitle, timeToContentEnd, {'metric2' : timeToContentEnd});
    } else {
        alert('end content section ' + tipo_lector + ' ' + timeToContentEnd);
    }
    endContent = true;
}
```

It works smoothly, showing the alert message when the user reaches the end of the content div. However if I try to duplicate the same with another div element (for example the comments section), the alert window popups when the user start to scroll. I have just copied & paste the code for the div content and changed the variables like:

```
   // If user has hit the bottom of the comment section send an event
    if (bottom >= $('#comments').scrollTop() + $('#comments').innerHeight() && !endComments) {
        currentTime = new Date();
        commentsScrollEnd = currentTime.getTime();
        timeToCommentsEnd = Math.round((commentsScrollEnd - scrollStart) / 1000);

        var palabras3 = document.getElementById('comments').innerHTML.split(' ').length;

        var tiempo_estimado_lector3 =  Math.round(palabras3 / 400)*60;
        var tiempo_estimado_lector_intensivo3 =  Math.round(palabras3 / 250)*60;

        if (timeToCommentsEnd < tiempo_estimado_lector3) {
        var tipo_lector3 = "Escaneador";
        } else if (timeToCommentsEnd < tiempo_estimado_lector_intensivo3) {
            var tipo_lector3 = "Lector";
            } else {
            var tipo_lector3 = "Lector intensivo";
            }
        if (!debugMode) {
            ga('set', 'dimension6', tipo_lector3); 
            ga('send', 'event', 'Reading', 'CommentsBottom', pageTitle, timeToCommentsEnd, {'metric3' : timeToCommentsEnd});
        } else {
            alert('end comments section ' + tipo_lector + ' ' + timeToCommentsEnd);
        }
        endComments = true;
    }
```

Is this procedure just fine once per pageview? It makes no sense!!

The whole code (and a demo): http://agustin-suarez.com/demos/grupo-categorias/

Comment: I'm not seeing analytics.js on the page. Did you remove it?

Comment: Sorry @Blexy. I forgot to mention that I am still not pushing data into analytics and sending them just in the alert window :)